# How can I use System.Net.HttpWebRequest with async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, portable-class-library

I've been trying to write a simple HTTP client as a Portable Class Library with minimum dependencies, which made me think that I should use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

I've [looked at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx), but it shows only `GetResponse`/`GetResponseStream` methods, which I don't have in my implementation. I only have `BeginGetResponse`, `BeginGetResponseStream`, etc. I've tried using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to convert this to a `Task`, but that only returns a `Task`, not a `Task<HttpWebResponse>`.

Is the correct approach here to use a cast, such as the following?

```
var response = (Task<HttpWebResponse>)Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse);
```

Or am I missing something?

**edit: I don't want to introduce dependencies on additional NuGet packages, since all I need to do is a single HTTP request in one place in a tiny library.**

Comment: You should use `GetResponseAsync`. Not sure if that's available in a PCL though. The **System.Net.HttpClient** NuGet package is probably a better choice than using `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

Comment: You were looking in the wrong place. The full documentation is at [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx).

Comment: But that means I need to add dependencies to my library. All I'm really doing is just a single HTTP request, it feels like an overkill to add a nuget package just for that.

Comment: @JakubArnold: But this NuGet package is focused on doing exactly what you need. Would you object to adding a reference to `Microsoft.Net.Http` if it was part of the base class library and not a download? Like it or not Microsoft is delivering more and more class libraries using NuGet.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Could you elaborate on the benefits of `HttpClient`? I understand that it's a little easier to do `async` with, but does it also have performance advantages, etc.?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: The library is portable and can be used on many platforms. It is detached from the .NET Framework Base Class Library so Microsoft can iterate and deliver up to date functionality at a much faster pace. Microsoft is moving a lot of libraries to NuGet which enable both them and us to develop in a more agile manner.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Right, I get that. But considering that the OP is only going to write this code in one place in a small library, he's unlikely to gain much from Microsoft's ability to deliver new functionality more quickly. `WebRequest` is portable, and can be used on many platforms as well. And Nuget dependencies add complexity--maybe not a ton, but it adds cost. Longer build times, more disk space, more risk of versioning issues, etc. *for every project that consumes his library*. Is there something really compelling about `HttpClient` that would make it worth that cost to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a generic `Task<>.Factory` you get a little more type-safety:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.google.com");
object state = null; // or whatever state you want.
var task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
    request.BeginGetResponse,
    request.EndGetResponse, 
    state);
```

However, as with when you're not doing `async` calls, if you want an `HttpWebResponse` rather than just a `WebResponse`, you'll need to do an additional cast. And be sure to close/dispose your response:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) (await task))
{
    // use response
}
```